# I am getting errors saying that the comparisons are not valid, whats wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am a new coder skimming the basics of JavaScript, and was trying to follow this tutorial but could not get this to work. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?")

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);

if (computerChoice > 0 && < 0.33) {
  (computerChoice = "rock");
}
  else if (computerChoice > 0.34 && < 0.66) {
  (computerChoice = "paper");
}
  else (computerChoice > 0.67 && < 1) {
  (computerChoice = "scissors");
}
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5kyqkf

Comment: You have to use `computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice < 0.33`. also, you can't use an expression with the `else` condition.use another `else if` for that.

Comment: Now it is saying this : http://prntscr.com/5kyto2

Comment: The last else can just be `else { computerChoice = 'scissors';}` since that's the only one left. Or you can initialise *computerChoice* to scissors and remove the else block entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
(computerChoice > 0 && < 0.33)
```

While this read well in English, it is not valid in most programming languages, JavaScript included. `&&` comes between two boolean values; `<` comes between two values and evaluates to a boolean value. When you say `< 0.33`, there is no value to be compared to `0.33`, and JavaScript gets confused. You need to write:

```
(computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice < 0.33)
```

Same with other such lines.

---

Also, please do post all relevant data in the future, as SLaks said, it is important. And I can't believe it was easier to make a printscreen, post it online, paste the link and annoy everyone, than to just type four words. Additionally, pay attention to formatting and indentation: sometimes those can hide errors, and they make the code very hard to read.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?"),
    computerChoice =  Math.random(),
    response = "";

console.log(computerChoice);

if (computerChoice > 0 &&  computerChoice < 0.33){
    response = "rock";
}
else if ( computerChoice > 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.66 ){`
    response = "paper";
}
else if ( computerChoice > 0.67 && computerChoice < 1 ){
    response = "scissors";
}
else{
    response = "Invalid option";
}

console.log(response);
```

The advices:

1. Try to keep the correctly identation to read the code easy.
2. Try to use an specific type for the vars, because if you have a large code you can have issues related to the types.

Corrections:

1. You have mistake in the comparison, add `(value > something && value > something)`.
2. You need to add an else if on the comparison `(computerChoice > 0.67 && < 1)`, and an else for another situation, like an invalid option (you can control this, but in your case it's necessary).

Kind regards, I hope that this help you.